# Setting variable equal to sqlite3+Python database entry

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have a table called printer which has the columns: id, printer_name, printer_status (referring to 3D printers). I am trying to retrieve the status of a specific printer (either 'Busy' or 'Ready') which will then be used to check and see if that printer can be used to print an item. The problem I am running into is that I don't  know how to do it lol.

When this runs, the output is '<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x03B1D4E0>', is there a way to get this to be the actual text value in that table cell. I want print(status) to output either 'Busy' or 'Ready'.

Hopefully this makes sense. If you need any additional information just ask, I am new to programming so I am unsure if I have supplied enough information.

```
def check_printer_status():
     id = input("Enter an id: )
     status = str(c.execute("SELECT printer_status FROM printer WHERE id =(?)",(id,)))
     print(status)
     if status == 'Ready':
         print_job.execute_print_job(id) #Set print_job_status = in-progress. Print_job is a different table
     if status == 'Busy'
         print_job.execute_print_job_pending(id) #Set print_job_status = pending
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are attempting to print the cursor object. The sqlite3 cursor object has two methods for returning the results of a query: `fetchall()` and `fetchone()`. When trying to test out your code i noticed you are missing quotation marks on the `id = input("Enter an id: )`.

As you are only returning one row from the query, use `c.fetchone()` (I am presuming 'c' is your `conn.cursor()`). This will then give you a list with one element so use the index 0 `[0]` to get that first element.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('test123.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def check_printer_status():
    id = input("Enter an id: ")
    c.execute("SELECT printer_status FROM printer WHERE id = ?", [id])
    status = c.fetchone()[0]
    print(status)
    if status == 'Ready':
        print_job.execute_print_job(id) #Set print_job_status = in-progress. Print_job is a different table
    elif status == 'Busy':
        print_job.execute_print_job_pending(id) #Set print_job_status = pending

check_printer_status()
```

Comment: The documentation for sqlite3 should be able to help you in future https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 0):

usually you have to fetch the data after selecting:

```py
def check_printer_status():
     id = input("Enter an id:" )
     query = c.execute("SELECT printer_status FROM printer WHERE id =(?)",(id,))
     status=query.fetchall()
     print(status)
     if status == 'Ready':
         print_job.execute_print_job(id) #Set print_job_status = in-progress. Print_job is a different table
     if status == 'Busy'
         print_job.execute_print_job_pending(id) #Set print_job_status = pending
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the query return one record, you should use fetchone() in order to get the status.
See [here](https://pynative.com/python-cursor-fetchall-fetchmany-fetchone-to-read-rows-from-table/) for more.

```
def check_printer_status():
     id = input("Enter an id:" )
     query = c.execute("SELECT printer_status FROM printer WHERE id =(?)",(id,))
     status = query.fetchone()[0]
     if status == 'Ready':
         print_job.execute_print_job(id)
     if status == 'Busy':
         print_job.execute_print_job_pending(id)
```

Comment: @jrmanning I am glad I managed to assist. Feel free to up vote.

Comment: I tried to upvote, but unfortunately I am too new and my reputation is too low. Once I am able to, I will :). Thanks again